# IIS application pool access to remote directory on network

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

I am trying to create file in remote directory on network within .ashx asp.net handler using File.Create(string path)

I am getting error that access to this path is denied. I tried to change identity setting application pool to 'network service', to 'local system', still getting access denied.

Via file system manager I can create files in mentioned remote directory with no problems.

Maybe someone had this kind of problem? What setting could be useful in application pool to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a network user that has the appropriate rights, and assign the Application Pool Identity to use this network user.